# I'm locked inside Warmaiden's!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm stuck in Warmaiden's in Whiterun.I click the door and it says it is locked. If I unlock it the animation plays, but then nothing: it doesn't load, doesn't freeze... just nothing. This happens to both doors leading outside.

I'm just hanging out in Warmaiden's, stuck.

Comment: I've tried google and the creation kit, but I do not understand the creation kit and do not want to do more damage.

Comment: Are you playing on the PC?

Comment: is you're game pirated or downloaded for free?

Comment: @iMAGEbox That's an... odd question. This is not a bug likely caused by piracy.

Comment: @shanodin Sounds like PC if they've considered using the CK.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie derp.

Comment: @hi-there23 Do you have any mods installed? Have you ever used mods with this savegame?

Comment: @shanodin I agree it's not clear and this question could use a *lot* more information. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yes it is. my friend had same problem when he downloaded Skyrim for free from piratebay. but anyway try reloading saved game, if reloading cant fix problem it means this is bug.

Answer (score 4):

Steal weapons, food, just about everything you can, to make a guard come and take you to jail.

Comment: Bad punctuation, misspelled words, and not enough details. This answer honestly makes no sense. You may want to edit this.

Comment: That might just work.

Comment: It's so unlogical it became logical.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, now it makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's not a larger problem and it's just a glitch that will fix itself once Warmaiden's is unloaded, you can use teleport console commands to get out and get on with your adventuring life. (It sounds like you're on a PC, so you have access to the console.)

First, shut down Skyrim and make a backup of your save. You want to be able to back up to a known

Open the console with <kbd>`</kbd> (or <kbd>§</kbd> on some international keyboards – whatever key is below <kbd>Esc</kbd> and above <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

The console will open. Type `cow WhiterunWorld 5, -3` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. You should appear somewhere outside within Whiterun.

Alternatively, you can use the `coc` command to warp to another interior and try to exit there. For example, `coc WhiterunDragonsreach` will put you in Dragonsreach, right inside the front doors.

(If neither work the bug is more than just doors in Warmaiden's and we'll need more information about your installation of Skyrim.)

Comment: Well, no need to edit my answer now heh